# Is there a standard implementation of F# defaultArg accepting lazy?

Tags: f#

I need an implementation of `defaultArg` function with `Lazy` as second parameter. Here is a usage example:

```
defaultArgLazy option (lazy doSomeHeavyWorkThatShouldBeAvoided())
```

It's quite easy to implement

```
let defaultArgLazy o (p:'a Lazy) = 
  match o with 
  | Some v -> v 
  | None -> p.Force()
```

But I wonder if there is a standard implementation that I'm missing.

Comment: No, there's nothing standard for that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of anything built in, but here's a more general version of your function:

```
module Option =
    let lazyDefault f opt =
        match opt with
        | Some x -> x
        | None -> f()

let lazyVal = lazy 1
let opt = None

opt |> Option.lazyDefault lazyVal.Force  // returns 1
```

It takes any function of `(unit -> 'a)` instead of specifically a `Lazy<'a>'`, so you just pass through Lazy's `Force` method instead, and retain the guarantee that the evaluation only happens once.

Perhaps `Lazy.Force()` was added in F# on top of .NET's existing `Lazy.Value` so that you could use it more idiomatically with higher order functions.

Note that I have swapped the parameter order compared to the built-in `defaultArg` to be more consistent with functions in other modules and more convenient for piping/currying.

Answer (score 1):

If the lazy value is only used at a later point in code, it might also be an idea to use `defaultArg` and pass it a `Lazy<'a> option` as a first argument. That way choosing the option or the default argument is separated from when the result is evaluated.

Taking this idea, the function

```
let defaultArgLazy opt lazyDef =
  (defaultArg (Option.map Lazy.CreateFromValue opt) lazyDef).Value
```

would do what you want - as does the one by TheQuickBrownFox.